# ¿Cómo imprimo html limitando la cantidad de caracteres en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Necesito imprimir la descripción de un producto que se guardó previamente desde un editor de texto *WYSIWYG*, por lo que me guardó en la base de datos todo el texto junto a las etiquetas html.

A la hora de imprimir, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
{!! $item->descriptionProduct !!}
```

Como en la vista principal solo quiero un resumen de la descripción, estaba utilizando **Str::limit()** quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
{!! Str::limit($item->descriptionProduct, 20) !!}
```

El detalle es que, al no imprimirse todo el texto, las etiquetas de cierre de `<p>` no se imprimen, quedando abierto y desconfigurándome el sitio.

¿Hay alguna solución?

Comment: Puedes usar una librería como esta: https://github.com/judev/php-htmltruncator

Comment: Podrías quitar las etiquetas de tus variables, es decir, poner únicamente el texto y agregar las etiquetas después de limitar la descripción a 20 caracteres. Otra opción sería utilizar `substr()` para "armar" el texto con sus etiquetas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude realizarlo sin librerías.

```
@php
 $html = "$item->descriptionProduct";
 $text = strip_tags($html);
 $short_text = Str::limit($text, 15);
@endphp
{!! $html = str_replace($text, $short_text, $html); !!}
```